# Platform-independent math functions in Clojure(script)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How to access things like `sin`, `cos` or `PI` in a pure Clojure way?

For example, if I want to write a pure library, I mustn’t use anything like `(.PI Math)` (Java) or `(.‑PI js/Math)` (JS).

Comment: The "pure Clojure way" is to use interop with the host language when appropriate, as in this case.  Are you asking (a) whether there is a host-language-neutral math library or (b) how to write code for both Clojure and ClojureScript?  If the latter, have a look at https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Cljx: https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx

With it you can write something like:

```
(* 5 #+clj (.PI Math) #+cljs (.‑PI js/Math))
```

and have this code compiled properly to Clojure and ClojureScript.

As far as I know there’s no better way to write one code to be runned as Clojure/ClojureScript.

There are some plans to include platform detection in Clojure itself but I think it’s not ready yet.

Comment: I got some weird characters copying and pasting the js interop for Math/PI here, might be worth typing it yourself.  Good answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Official wrapper APIs: `clojure.math` & `cljs.math`

For simple constants or common mathematical functions, the first thing I'd reach for (other than interop) would be the [`clojure.math`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.math-api.html) and [`cljs.math`](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.math/) libs, which provide `cljs.math/PI`, `clojure.math/sin`, and so on.

## <s>Cljx</s>

Another answer suggests Cljx, which has been deprecated for a few years. See the [transition guide](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Using-cljc#transitioning-from-cljx), which is also a good overview of the new solution:

## `.cljc`

Code targeting multiple Clojure platforms is written in `.cljc` files using [reader conditionals](https://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals) (introduced in Clojure [1.7](https://clojure.org/news/2015/06/30/clojure-17#_portable_clojure_and_reader_conditionals)).

The excellent [kixi.stats](https://cljdoc.org/d/kixi/stats/0.5.2/doc/readme) implements platform-independent Clojure math using cljc, providing us not only a useful library but also a nice example of the approach. An excerpt:

```clj
(def PI
  #?(:clj Math/PI
     :cljs js/Math.PI))

(defn sin [x]
  #?(:clj  (Math/sin x)
     :cljs (js/Math.sin x)))

(def infinity
  #?(:clj Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY
     :cljs js/Infinity))
```

This code is from [`kixi.stats.math`](https://github.com/MastodonC/kixi.stats/blob/master/src/kixi/stats/math.cljc).

Answer (score -3):

Sin example:

```
(.sin js/Math 3)
```

PI example:

```
(aget js/Math "PI")
```

Displaying in console:

```
(.log js/console (aget js/Math "PI"))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How is that platform independent ?

Comment: Hi,Please read the title (I.E. it states "Clojurescript" :) The term "platform independent" is not definitive. Generally speaking, javascript is considered "platform independent" (as in, most modern OS's support standard jsvascript). The javascript Math library is standard. Thus, I would need to ask what platforms are you concerned about that don't support javascript? More importantly, why are you using Clojurescript on a platform that doesn't include standard javascript?

Comment: Did you even read the question? Platform in this case is the implementation of Clojure of course. You just showed how to do it on the Javascript platform (which I did in the question already, btw.).

Comment: Hi, Please edit the question so that includes your definition of "platform". Please edit the title :) Folks can only answer the question you ask:) The more specific your question, the less ambiguities, the better the answers :) Good Luck :)

Comment: IMHO it’s pretty clear from the question. yonki seems to think that, too, because his answer relates to the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the answer in here, it helped me.